# Handling background YouTube video not playing with tubular.js

Tags: javascript, html, flash, youtube

I'm using tubular.js to run a youtube video as a background. It obviously breaks when browsers do not support HTML5 and do not have flash detected.

When it breaks, the background has a call to action to install flash, but this call to action is not clickable, for it was layered behind other items.

How do I handle instances when flash and HTML5 are not installed or supported?

Comment: I edited your question (and phrased it to become an actual question).. by plugin `tubular.js` are you referring to jQuery's Tubular JS plugin: http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/` .. downloadable here: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-tubular/` ?

Comment: sometimes this issue appears by this id 'tubular-shield' just set its height:0%; in js , and you are able to click video and play

Answer (score 1):

Our solution was to use the SWF Object (https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to detect for flash.

When flash was not detected we served up an image instead of the full screen video.

This accounted for the lowest common denominator.

```
    if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9.0.18")) {
        //has flash show video
    }
    else {
        //no flash show image   
    }
```

For tubular.js we wrapped the following:

```
    if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9.0.18")) {
        $('#home').tubular({
            videoId: 'YOURVIDEOID'
        }); 
    }
    else {
        $.backstretch([
            "/img/theme/background/1.jpg"
        ]);     
    }
```

Comment: probably a good solution until a feature detection framework like modernizer supports flash detection. still, I'm not keen on loading this swfobject project for a utility method -> feature detection

Answer (score -1):

the youtube html5 iframe api  - which is used by tubular - won't do anything without html5 on a browser...

you would need to setup a flash fallback (or an image as proposed above..)